# Windows MongoDB - Installed Compass but can't find Compass within system

Tags: mongodb, windows-7, mongodb-compass

I ran the MongoDB Community Version Download Setup with the GUI for Mongo -
 Compass checked. No problems with the installation and the setup was successfully completed.

However after the setup I couldn't find Compass installed anywhere in my system.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Even the C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin didn't have a executable file or dll for compass.

[image]

What happened to Compass?

Comment: No idea, but how about downloading it separately? https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?filter=enterprise?jmp=nav#compass

Comment: @dnickless Thank you I will try this as well

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For some reason in Windows 10 it is installed into the hidden AppData directory. At least I found first a shortcut 'MongoDB Compass' here:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MongoDB Inc
```

and then in the properties of it the actual location seems to be

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\MongoDBCompass.exe
```

Comment: I tested the path but i couldn't fined it at all

Comment: I found the .exe file under a different folder but executed and nothing happened so it's better to download and install Compass individually.

Comment: `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompassCommunity` on win7

Answer (score 9):

I wound up downloading and installing Compass separately.  It's available from the [Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=hero#compass).  You can select the version and OS there: [Compass Download Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1zn8.jpg).

The installer lets you choose the destination directory.  You can also add a Desktop shortcut in Windows.

Hope that helps!

Dave

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem

Step 1: Make hidden folder visible

step 2: C:\Users\shankar\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompassCommunity

Step 3: Click on MongoDBCompassComunity edition

You will have compass gui open

Enjoy your Compass Community Edition

Comment: To prevent going in that directory everytime, make a shortcut on desktop or taskbar. Also, the issue doesn't seem to appear on downloading the `.msi` variant from their site.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue where MongoDB installer wouldn't work at all so I had to choose customize instead of the easy install. The location of the file for Compass should be in:

C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompassCommunity

as @Jonez said, mine is for the Community edition. Make sure you have your hidden files view enabled. On a side note, I encountered less problems when I used administrative capabilities.

Comment: Validated for windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the compass was not installing at all, but I was getting successful message like you.

I figured that there is `InstallCompass.ps1` powershell script in the bin folder.

I opened powershell and got into bin folder and launched it

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin
.\InstallCompass.ps1
```

...and voila! it downloaded and installed the compass appropriately using command line

Comment: Nice! The real answer for the current version!

Comment: It just opens the file, nothing else. Not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found exe in following paths:

C:\ProgramData\<**your user id**>\MongoDBCompass\MongoDBCompass.exe

C:\ProgramData\<**your user id**>\MongoDBCompass\app-1.11.1\MongoDBCompass.exe

Answer (score 3):

1. After installing the Mongo DB Compass .msi Setup installer.
2. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoDB Compass Installer and run that setup.
3. Connect your DB.

[image: Compass .exe Setup file location]

Answer (score 2):

I'm on windows 10 and can confirm compass even after checking install compass option during installation did not install. That wasn't surprising considering compass is 158 MB and mongo db download was very quick.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I got the same problem in windows 7 when I downloaded MongoDB Compass Zip file from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass and run 'MongoDBCompass.exe'

[image: don't download zip file for mongodb compass]

Then I downloaded the `.msi` file instead of zip, installed the .msi file and 'MongoDB Compass' icon added in the start menu.

Click on the 'platform' option and select MSI.

[image: mongodb compass msi file]

Comment: do you an idea as to why this might be happening?

Comment: @lucasreta still I have no idea.

Comment: @lucasreta I believe when you download `.msi` it runs it as an executable, whereas if you download the zip it appears to be preinstalled and unpackaged, since clicking on the app inside zip directly opens the application instead of opening the installer.

Comment: Worked for me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with the msi installer, I tried with the exe and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue so, i have downloaded the exe just in case if u want the. link:https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass

Answer (score -2):

I also had the same issue. And I have found that, it occurred when try to install the mongo db more than one time.