# Installed MongoDB but it is not showing up in program files or in uninstall or change a program

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDB for windows 64 bit that I installed from (http://www.mongodb.org/downloads), the whole process of installing was okay. When I finished the installation and got back to my C:\Program Files there I found nothing. Then I restarted my laptop but found nothing. I again installed it, this time I installed it with customize option in 'D' directory but again no folder was found and it is not installed. Even I searched its files but no file was found. What's the issue here?
Thanks in advance for any help in this regard.

Comment: Just go to your C: or D: drive and search mongo etc. in the search bar, you'll find it.

Comment: I have done it before but found nothing.

Comment: And now, when I click for repair it says u cannot perform this action on installed softwares. and I found nothing not in search, program files of C:, not in D: and even not in windows search. i am wondering where the hell it's gone.... please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install:

1. Run the installer without Compass selected.
2. Download Compass as a separate installation file (from the tabs on the download page of Mongo) and install it.

When you try to connect to the server from Compass you will see that the server is not running.

To get the server running:

1. Look under C:\Program Files\3.6\bin and run mongod.exe
2. In Compass try to connect to the server again

If you are still not able to connect make sure you have the default database path created:
C:\data\db

Then run mongod.exe again.

It should be able to connect now without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck here too until I reinstalled, but un-clicked the "install mongodb compass" option right before I completed the installation. The installation worked and mongodb finally appeared on the program files directory, whereas before it gave me an error before the installation completed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this URL - [Windows MongoDB - Installed Compass but can't find Compass within system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696519/windows-mongodb-installed-compass-but-cant-find-compass-within-system/64430831#64430831)

**Install `.msi` file instead of .exe from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass, then you get the shortcut icon in start option and uninstall option.**