# How to relaunch MongoDB Compass on windows machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I installed a *mongo db* version of *1.20.5* `mongodb-compass-1.20.5-win32-x64` on my windows machine and it launches its self automatically after installation. 
When i close it, i cannot find its icon on desktop to launch it.
I used Mongodb Compass documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/install/ but i could not find how to relaunch
I tried to look for it in the program files but i could not find it but its in the list of installed programs.
Please, how can i launch it again.

Comment: May be you will find it in the Windows _Start -> All Programs_.

Comment: I checked but still i could not find it

Comment: It should be listed at: _Control Panel -> Programs (Uninstall a program)_. Also, _Start -> Search for Programs and Files (search box); enter Compass_, it should show up.

Comment: I can see it in the "Uninstall a program" list but cannot see it in the search box if i type "Compass"

Comment: I don't know what the issue is. May be try to uninstall and install it again. I am using Compass 1.19 on Windows OS and I was able to do all the things I had mentioned in the above comments.

Answer (score 1):

By default, it installs in:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\
```

But,  if you are not Admin, it installs here:

```
C:\Users\{your user}\AppData\Local\Programs
```

If you don't find it, try this:

1. Open `This PC`
2. In the "Search on This PC" type **Compass** and press Enter
3. Wait until Windows finishes searching

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** - Install `.msi` file instead of `.exe` from *https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass*, then you get the shortcut icon in start option and uninstall option.

Ref URL - [Windows MongoDB - Installed Compass but can't find Compass within system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696519/windows-mongodb-installed-compass-but-cant-find-compass-within-system/64430831#64430831)